# Как определить какой именно POST запрос приходит в HttpHandler?

Tags: c#, json, http, сервер, iis

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть сервер, написанный на c#, на который я делаю POST запрос с клиента и обрабатываю HttpHandler-ом. В один и тот же хэндлер мне надо послать два разных запроса. Как понять какой именно запрос пришел? 
Я делал через свойство ContentType, примерно вот так:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{

       string contentType = context.Request.ContentType;

       if (contentType == "Request 1")
       {
          using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
           {
               json = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
           }
          Method1(json);
       }
       else
       {
           using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
           {
               json = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
           }
          Method2(json);
       }
 }
```

В каждый метод приходит разный JSON, и , следовательно, при десериализации у меня выскочит ошибка.
Насколько я понимаю, мой метод очень не безопасен, поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью.. Подскажите, как лучше реализовать мою задачу?

Comment: Эээ... а какого типа ваша переменная `json`? Строка? А где код десериализации? В любом случае при десериализации _возможна_ ошибка (т. к. данные приходят из сети), учитывайте это.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несколько вариантов на выбор:

1. Использовать разный Url. Проиписать в конфиге один и тот же Handler дважды, с разным path. В коде проверять Url.
2. Добавить GET-параметр с типом действия (да, это POST, но передача параметров через `myhandler.ashx?action=action1` при этом все равно будет работать).
3. Если есть возможность - добавить кастомный хедер. Почти любой клиент это позволяет. Совсем не обязательно использовать только существующие заголовки, вроде Content Type. Например, на jquery:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: 'foo/bar',
       headers: { 'x-my-custom-action': 'action1' }
   });
   ```
4. Проверять содержимое json-строки, перед десериализацией (не самый лучший вариант - слишком хрупкий, и подразумевает вычитываение всего содержимого из запроса в строчку, поэтому последний в списке)